# Display Image related to a Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have scoured the Internet, ChatGPT, StackOverflow, etc, and cannot find out how to make an image from my AWS S3 bucket (from a foreign key) appear in my template. The images work perfectly fine when they aren't connected via a foreign key and I am showing just students and their images.

**views.py**

```
#@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.groups.filter(name='teacher').exists())
def hallpasses(request):
    students = HallPass.objects.filter(dateissued__date = todaysdate2.date )
    
    allstudents = Student.objects.all()

    

    context={'students':students,
             'todaysdate2':todaysdate2,
             'allstudents':allstudents,
             }
    return render(request, 'pass.html',context)
```

**models.py**

```
#HallPass model
class HallPass(models.Model):

    DESTINATIONS=(
        ('Activities Office', 'Activities Office'),
        ('Alumni Office', 'Alumni Office'),
        ('Cafeteria', 'Cafeteria'),
        ('Chelsea Center', 'Chelsea Center'),
        ('Counseling Center', 'Counseling Center'),
        ('Cr. Counselor', 'Cr. Counselor'),
        ('Library', 'Library'),
        ('Nurse', 'Nurse'),
        ('Office 124', 'Office 124'),
        ('Office 157', 'Office 157'),
        ('Office 210', 'Office 210'),
        ('Office 308', 'Office 308'),
        ('Other', 'Other'),
        ('Locker', 'Locker'),
        ('Main Office', 'Main Office'),
        ('Teachers Room', 'Teachers Room'),
        ('Restroom', 'Restroom'),
        ('Water', 'Water'),
        ('WGHS Academy', 'WGHS Academy'),
        ('Art Department','Art Department'),
        ('Business Department','Business Department'),
        ('English Department','English Department'),
        ('FACS Department','FACS Department'),
        ('Industrial Tech Department','Industrial Tech Department'),
        ('Math Department','Math Department'),
        ('Music Department','Music Department'),
        ('Makerspace','Makerspace'),
        ('PE Department','PE Department'),
        ('Science Department','Science Department'),
        ('Social Studies Department','Social Studies Department'),
        ('SSD Department','SSD Department'),
        ('Theater Arts Department','Theater Arts Department'),
        ('World Languages','World Languages'),




    )

    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
    dateissued = models.DateTimeField(null=False,blank=False)
    teacherissuing = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Teacher Issuing: ")
    #code = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='static/images/code/') 
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=6)
    pass_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    #email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254,default=1)
    owner = models.IntegerField("Request Owner", blank=False, default=1)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, choices = DESTINATIONS)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "" + str(self.student) + ", " + str(self.dateissued)
```

```
#Student model
class Student(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254,blank=True)
    eligible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254,blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank=True )

    def first_image(self):
        #code to determine image
        return self.images.first()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lastname + ", " + self.firstname 
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['lastname', 'firstname']
```

**Template where image will not appear**

```
{% for i in students %}
    <tr>
    <Td>
    #image will not load here
    <img src="{{ i.images.url }}" alt="" width="auto" height="340"/></Td>
        <td><b>{{i.student}}</b></td>
        <td >{{i.teacherissuing}}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">{{i.dateissued |date:"M d, Y H:i"}}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">{{i.duration}}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">{{i.pass_number}}</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">{{i.destination}}</td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

---

I have tried related_name, nested loops, filtering, i.images.url, etc. It is important to note that the images are stored in an AWS S3 bucket and that is working perfectly fine for uploading to the bucket and it does deliver the images on a template that shows all students (the image is not a foreign key relation in this context). The image only fails to load when attempt to connect to it through a foreign key relationship.

Comment: `{{ i.student.image.url }}`?

Comment: Can you try `{{ i.image.url }}`, so images -> image?

Answer (score 0):

In your template file, the place where you used `{{ i.images.url }}`, instead use  this `{{ i.student.image.url }}`.
This will access the image field of the Student model that is related to the HallPass instance.

You can try this:

```
{% for i in students %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="{{ i.student.image.url }}" alt="" width="auto" height="340"/>
        </td>
        <td><b>{{ i.student }}</b></td>
        <td>{{ i.teacherissuing }}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">{{ i.dateissued | date:"M d, Y H:i" }}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">{{ i.duration }}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">{{ i.pass_number }}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">{{ i.destination }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, check the AWS S3 bucket permissions and CORS settings to make sure your Django app is authorized to access the images.

Hopefully, this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your template, `i` are *not* `Student` objects, but `HallPass` objects. So in order to access the image, you first need to get the corresponding `.student`, so:

```
{% for i in students %}
    <!-- … -->
    {{ i.student.image.url }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that you can boost performance by prefetching the students with:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.groups.filter(name='teacher').exists())
def hallpasses(request):
    students = HallPass.objects.select_related('student').filter(
        dateissued__date=todaysdate2.date
    )
    allstudents = Student.objects.all()
    context = {
        'students': students,
        'todaysdate2': todaysdate2,
        'allstudents': allstudents,
    }
    return render(request, 'pass.html', context)
```